# Solr- Reason behind the result of Fuzzy Search highlighting

Tags: solr, highlight, fuzzy-search

I have Solr 6.2.0 running fuzzy search and it returns highlighting result that I dont really understand why:

- Query: oa
- Hightlight: **Awad** **Mohamed** Ahmed Ibn **OAF**

Why would Awad and Mohamed also highlighted? When not using fuzzy search, the hightlight is correct(Only OAF).
Some other hightlights with the same query:

1. **Daltransgaz**, **OAO**
2. VO **Tekhnopromeksport**, **OAO**

Query config:

```
Word Percentage: 60
Phrase Percentage: 60
Score Algorithm: QUERY WORD
Alogrithm: Damerau Levensthein
```

Query param as seen in request

```
 "params":{
      "debug":"results",
      "hl":"on",
      "group.cache.percent":"100",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"*,score",
      "start":"0",
      "fq":"{!percentagefilter p=0.6}",
      "rows":"48",
      "group.ngroups":"true",
      "hl.simple.pre":"<span class=\"highlight\">",
      "q":"{!percentage f=nam_comp_name t=QUERY_SIDE pw=0.6 ic=1 icp=0.59 alg=DA_LV}oa~",
      "hl.simple.post":"</span>",
      "group.truncate":"true",
      "requestId":"4",
      "hl.fl":"nam_comp_name",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"ent_id",
      "group":"true"}},
```

Comment: Please add in your question the fuzzy search Solr configuration you're using.

Comment: @freedev: I added the param for the request and also enable debug. But they only have the info about the score of each fuzzy search, not the information of the highlight. I am also new to Solr

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you're using the [Phonetic Matching](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Phonetic+Matching) (or Soundex) together to Damerau-Levensthein distance algorithm.

This would explain why `oa` search would match also A**wa**d M**oha**med.

Comment: If so, why it returned the whole Awad highlighted, not just the wa?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the highlight will be executed on the word (entire word) and not a part of it.